# Excel: How to transfer names to numbers?

Tags: excel

I have 1200 names in Column A. 18 names are the same. I want to code these names from 1 till 18. Assume the Excel file is:

```html
Name Code
John Smith 1
Rose Adam 2
King john 3
John Smith 1
King john 3
Tim Gohl 4
B.smith 5
Tim Ghol 4
. .
. .
. .
```

Is it possible to code the names as 1, 2, 3...? 
Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your names are in column A starting from Row2, then try this...

In B2

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,MAX(B$1:B1)+1,INDEX(B$2:B2,MATCH(A2,A$2:A2,0)))
```

and then copy it down.
[image]